# How to debug projects not built by makefile and cmake

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, ide, uwsgi

I am learning UWSGI source code and I would like to try debugging it

First, I execute the build command for uwsgi: python uwsgiconfig.py --build

Then I configure the debugging files for vscode:

```
      "name": "(lldb)",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "/project/uwsgi/uwsgi", 
      "args": [
        "--ini",
        "/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini"
      ],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "lldb",
      "miDebuggerPath":"/usr/bin/lldb"
    }
```

Finally, it was found that debugging was not possible. I have collected some information and learned that vscode can only debug projects built by cmake and makefile

May I ask how to handle this situation. Do you think there are other ways to switch to another IDE

my experience is not very rich, but I know that not all projects have makefiles and cmakes. When encountering this situation, what IDE is used for debugging (except for gdb, which is too difficult to use)

Comment: First of all you need to make sure the program is built with debug information (the `-g` flag when building with GCC or Clang). That will help you see the source code when you step through the code in the debugger.

Comment: And it's wrong that VSCode can only debug code built by certain build-systems. Who told you that? Where did you get that information from? The debugger you have configured, `lldb`, can handle all kinds of executable programs built for your host system. Can you please [edit] your question and give us more details about the actual problem you have with debugging? What happens when you try? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  I use the “ python uwsgiconfig.py --build ” command to compile and generate the “uwsgi” executable program . After configuring launch.json as mentioned above, the following information will be output: “error: unknown option: --interpreter=mi Use 'lldb --help' for a complete list of options.”

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification, don't use comments for this purpose. Show the source code you are trying to debug as a [mre] in your question. Where does `--interpreter=mi` come from.

Comment: Such information should be in the question itself. But it do tell me there's something wrong with your configuration, not a problem with debugging in itself.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thx!!  I not add “-g” flag  when build the code